# Commits in branch are recorded in master branch after local merge and push

Tags: git, github, merge, version-control

Here's my problem:

1. I have a Github repository that I've `clone`ed locally, so there's a local `master` branch that tracks `origin/master`.
2. I create a new local branch `foobar`, which I publish to the remote Github repository with the command `git push origin foobar`. At this point, on Github I can see both the `master` and `foobar` branches. As I push my subsequent local commits in `foobar` to remote, those commits can be seen under the `foobar` branch in Github.
3. Locally, I `git checkout master` to move to the `master` branch and run `git merge foobar` to merge my changes into `master`.
4. I run `git push` to push the changes to Github.

The problem is that on Github, the commits I made in the `foobar` branch (in step 2) are recorded as commits in the `master` branch! This can be seen by viewing the network graph in my Github repository's Insights tab: the commits I made in `foobar` show up as dots on the line representing `master`. In other words, local merges appear to put all commits into the `master` branch as far as Github is concerned, but this is not the "history" I want for my repository!

However, if I repeat the steps above until step 3, then I create a merge pull request **within** Github to merge `foobar` into `master`, the commits in `foobar` will appear as within that branch. I can confirm this by viewing the network graph within the Github repository's Insights tab (i.e. my commits in `foobar` show up as dots within the `foobar` line instead of the `master` line).

Is there a way to run my local git commands so that I don't need to merge on the Github website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done is called a fast-forward merge.  In other words, when the branch you're merging (`foobar`) is a superset of the branch you're merging into (`master`), by default Git just updates the two branches to be the same.

When you perform a merge on GitHub, GitHub by default always performs a non-fast-forward merge; that is, it always creates a merge commit.  This is useful for tracking changes, and if that's the behavior you want locally, you can use the `--no-ff` option: `git merge --no-ff foobar`.

This is mostly a matter of style and preference as to what you want.  Some projects prefer a linear history with no merge commits and some prefer to track individual features explicitly with merge commits.

Comment: That worked, thank you @bk2204! I do wonder why the Github default is different from the git default... Anyway, it's good to know that there's an option between fast-forward vs non-fast-forward commits.